# Unable to drag and move around files in Project Navigator in Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode6.1, project-navigator

I am unable to drag my classes (and other files) around in my Project navigator (Xcode 6.1), and I am unsure of when this problem began. It might have been when I updated Xcode from 6.0 to 6.1.

I have been able to do this before and would like to be able to again, as I prefer to re-organize the structure of the project as it grows. I am also unable to create new groups since this happened. When I click "New group" I can see a new folder in the tree structure, but only for half a second before it disappears again.

Can anyone help me with this?

This is not an issue if a create a new project. This is only happening in this particular project I am working on.

Comment: may be some source control problem?

Comment: @mityaika07 I am fairly new to Objective-C, and tried to learn abou source control, but I found no solution.This problem only appears when I open the project from my computer. The project was made on another computer (on which this issue does not exist) and then downloaded on mine. It is only in this project, not if I create new projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new file in my project, which worked just fine, and when the file was created and showing in my Project navigator I could see a number of empty groups named New group1, New group2 and so on. They must be the groups I tried to create without (visible) results.

Suddenly, everything works as it should. I can now move my files around again by dragging them.

Must be som kind of a bug?

Answer (score 17):

I'd try out the following:

- Make sure that you don't have anything in your file filter text field at the bottom of your project navigator
- Try restarting Xcode
- Try starting a new project to see if you still have the same issue. If you do, try deleting and reinstalling Xcode.

Comment: I checked and I don't have anything in my filter text field. When I create a new project I am able to move the files and add new groups! Might be like @mityaika07 says, a a source control problem. Don't know what that means, but I will look it up.

Comment: Thanks man! The first point solved my problem (Make sure that you don't have anything in your file filter text field at the bottom of your project navigator)

Comment: Had bought the latest MacBook (touchbar). Playing around with it and soon enough, Xcode stopped working properly. Thanks for the tips (it was the first point).

Answer (score 3):

just as Adam Kaump said, I solve the problem by deleting the file filter text at the bottom .